# Is there a ways I can replace some specific words to some specific words?

Tags: python

I know this is a very basic question that can do with .replace (but I think i'll have to make a lot of .replace), and for me, is there any cleaner way to do it, because I'm still learning Python, I still don't know plenty of stuff in this language, so please pardon me. (Whenever I search "How to replace a word with a word, it only shows .replace method, so I don't know if there's another method for this.)

What a replace can do:

I have read this example on W3schools

```
txt = "I like bananas"

x = txt.replace("bananas", "apples")
```

But what I want is, in 1 input, sometimes, for example, I might write `JS` and it'll become `Javascript`, `p`, it'll become `Python`, or let's say `fb`, it'll become `Facebook`, etc, I mean, it's a lot of some words I want to replace it from shortcut words into properly words

Can I somehow use 1 variable but it stores some sort of "Shortcut words" and then replaces it with 1 variable that stores properly word?

For example:

```
shortcutWord = {js, fb, p}

properlyWord = {Javascript, Facebook, Python}
```

And it'll understand like, js suitable for Javascript, fb for Facebook, etc, I don't know how to describe it specifically, but is there a way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you use a dictionary? `d={'js': 'javascript', 'fb': 'facebook'}`, etc.

Comment: Use a dict and iterate over it and call replace for each of their key, values

Comment: I don't know about this, but I have a quick look, it looks like a JSON does it? To be more specific, I have an input word on my screen, let's say I pressed/enter the input is Facebook, it'll trace back into the "Facebook" object in my JSON and display, but now I want to press/input only fb on my screen, not "Facebook" word anymore, can it still work?

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question?

All you need is to input 2 parallel arrays that have the shortcuts and the long words. This could be written nicer through the use of dictionaries, however, I assumed you required the two parallel arrays.

```py
shortcut_word = ["js", "fb", "p"]

properly_word = ["Javascript", "Facebook", "Python"]

txt = "I like js and i use fb"

def properfySentence(txt, shortcuts, full_words):
    words = txt.split(' ') # split the sentence into an array of words

    for word in words: # loop through the words...
        if word in shortcuts: # and check if the word is in the shortcuts
            words[words.index(word)] = full_words[shortcuts.index(word)] # replace the shortcut with the full length word

    txt_changed = ' '.join(words) # rejoin the words with spaces
    
    return txt_changed # return the result

print(
    properfySentence(txt,shortcut_word,properly_word)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your instruction, I'll try and feedback to you in a few minutes or so!

Comment: I've tried a bit of this, I've managed to split my input, but then I realize something, what if it's 2 proper words that I want to use only 1 shortcut word? Like... let's say "Internet Protocol" if I press "ip" then it'll not work, I guess that will happen from what I imagine how to code work since we split it into each word, isn't it?

Comment: @MeowMeowpram You should be able to add Internet Protocol into the properly_word and it should still work

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Syntax:

```
txt = "I like FB"
trans_dict = {'js': 'javascript', 'fb': 'facebook', 'FB' : 'Facebook' }

for word, replace_word in trans_dict.items():
  txt = txt.replace(word, replace_word)

print(txt)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help a lot, I'll try it :D

Comment: @AlainT. sorry my mistake it only works for pandas data frames e.g. ```df["Group"] = df["Group"].replace({"A": "Group A", "B": "Group B", "C": "Group C"}) updated the answer with another solution that works for strings

Comment: If the dictionary happens to contain `{js:"javascript", "ip":"Internet Protocol"}` Then 'js' will be replaced by 'javascrInternet Protocolt'. Also any word containing one of the keywords will be modified. You need to work on a word by word basis, not on the whole text. For example `" ".join(trans_dict.get(w,w) for w in txt.split(" "))`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a replace() function based on the re module (regular expressions) leveraging its ability to isolate words.:

```
import re

def replace(s,d): 
    return re.sub(r"\w+",lambda m:d.get(m.group(),m.group()),s)
```

*The re.sub() function allows use of a function (or lambda) to get the replacement values. so each word (found by `\w+`) is either replaced or stays the same based on the result of d.get()*

Example usage:

```
subs = {"js":"javacript","fb":"Facebook","py":"Python"}    
text = "I'm happy with py but I despise js, and fb"

print(replace(text,subs))

I'm happy with Python but I despise javascript, and Facebook
```

*Notice that the 'py' at the end of 'happy' was not accidentally replaced*

*Also note that the 'js' keyword was detected even though it is followed by a comma (not a space)*